# format numbers - engineering notation in R

Tags: r, format

The engineering notation of numbers is like scientific notation, but the exponent must be a multiple of 3. This is convenient because it relates to kilo,Mega,Giga,etc.

```
163500000   # the number
1.635E8     # scientific notation = what R does
163.5E6     # engineering notation = metric / SI prefix
```

Does R have a function to format numbers to SI prefixes? I can only discover the scientific notation. [there is a function [here](http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=tips%3adata-strings%3aformatengineering), dating from 2006].

Comment: What is the problem with the link given solution?

Comment: If i give the format in R via options, it becomes a solution that i don have to worry about anymore. When i apply the function in the link, i have to apply it exactly on the numeric columns, or it will mess up my data.frame.

Comment: Then apply it only to those columns which return `TRUE` for `is.numeric()`